# Multiple instance of same program, obtaining output

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, background-process

I have a shell program in Ubuntu 16.04, named `foo`, that outputs status update when I press any button. It's located in `/usr/local/bin/foo`, so I can call the program anywhere. The program works like this:

```
$ foo
Welcome
```

after I press a key, it will show:

```
Time now is 01:23:45
```

If I press `Ctrl-C`, it will exit just like most of the other shell programs.

I would like this `foo` program to be run in multiple instances. I know GNU Screen command can switch between tasks, but is it the correct way to do so?

Alternatively, I know that I can put the program to run in the background like this:

```
$ foo &
[1]  123456
```

Job ID 1 is created in the background and I can call it out by its Job ID:

```
$ fg %1
```

However, I need to put it back to background after obtaining the latest output of the program (by pressing any button: is there any method to do this programmatically?). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, your requirements are to be able to:

1. Run several instances of the program concurrently.
2. Get terminal control over any of the instances at any time.
3. Send instances back to background as soon as they output.

If we stick to the `&` approach, then yes, there is a shortcut for (3). When a program has control over a terminal, it can be sent to the background using a `SIGTSTP` signal. Conveniently enough, that's usually what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> does.

You could therefore have something like this:

```
$ foo &
Welcome
[1] 10

$ foo &
Welcome
[2] 11

$ fg %1
<ENTER>
Time now is 01:23:45
<Ctrl+Z>
[1]+ Stopped
```

To my knowledge, there is no such shortcut for `fg` (and how would you indicate which instance to bring back anyway?)

Note that the `SIGTSTP` signal does not actually need to come from the shell which started the process. If you `kill -TSTP` the process by PID in a second shell, you'll also be able to get it back with `fg` in the first.

> I need to put it back to background after obtaining the latest output of the program (by pressing any button: is there any method to do this programmatically?)

If by *programmatically* you mean that you have access to `foo`'s source code, then you can use what we've just seen. The `raise` system call can be used by a program to send itself a signal. If we take a very simplistic version of `foo`, we can have something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Welcome");
    while(getchar()) { /* Use termios to switch to unbuffered mode */
        fprintf(stdout, "The time is... something");
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stdin);
        raise(SIGTSTP);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now while this is all reasonably nice, I would agree that `screen` is probably a nicer way to do all this, mostly because you can name your screen sessions and therefore never need to remember a job or process ID. Just like the `&` approach, it also has the advantage of not requiring changes to the source code.

```
$ screen -S foo1
$ ./foo
Welcome
<Ctrl-a d>
[detached from 10.foo1]

$ screen -s foo1
<ENTER>
Time now is 01:23:45
<Ctrl-a d>
[detached from 10.foo1]
```

Another advantage here is that you do not need to stop your program before detaching. That's pretty convenient if you want it to do stuff in the background while you're not looking. In the previous approach, you would need to run `bg` every time you stop `foo`.

You can also get a list of running screens with `screen -ls`. On my machine, I've setup a few aliases in `~/.bashrc` to account for my extra laziness:

```bash
alias S='screen -S'
alias s='screen -r'
alias sls='screen -ls'
```

This way you could simply do things like `S foo1`, `s foo1`, ... Some might argue than one-character aliases can be a little annoying when you misplace a space or something in your commands, but I think `screen` is one of those programs which are [so convenient](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) that you can afford to make an exception.

Now assuming you're going with the `screen` approach, here's how you could  send a key to a session and fetch its last line of output from a shell. There are ways to tweak this (and I've allowed myself some shortcuts) but anyway. You can define the following function in `~/.bashrc` :

```bash
screen_key_tail() {
    screen -S $1 -X stuff "^M"
    tmp="$(mktemp)"
    screen -S $1 -X hardcopy "$tmp"
    grep -v ^$ "$tmp" | tail -n1
    rm "$tmp"
}
```

and call it with:

```
$ screen_key_tail foo1
```

where `foo1` is the name of the `screen` session you're targetting.